# how to map column names with new dataframe and replace it with new values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file as below 
df1:-

```
1  2  6  4
u  f  b  h
a  f  r  m
q  r  b  c
```

now I have another csv file as below
df2:-

```
cat dog fish sand  vent wear
1   2    3    4      5   6
```

now I want to write a python code which should map column name with 2nd csv and replace the value and I have total 1900 columns in df2 which i need to map.

output csv

```
   cat dog   wear  sand
    u   f    b     h
    a   f    r     m
    q   r    b     c
```

can any one help me with this

Comment: What is `df.columns.dtype`? You may be able to do `df.columns.map({v: k for k, v in df2.iloc[0].items()})` if the columns are numeric.

Comment: did you check replace ?, or rename

Comment: If someone is asking for clarification, you lose nothing by responding and stand to gain a more informed solution a lot sooner. Just FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to map df2 with `df.rename()`

```
#Convert df2 to dict and switch the string representations of the values with the keys
dct={str(v[0]):k for k,v in df2.to_dict(orient='list').items()}

df1.rename(mapper=dct, axis=1, inplace=True)

    cat dog wear    sand
0   u   f   b       h
1   a   f   r       m
2   q   r   b       c

df1.rename(mapper={str(v[0]):k for k,v in df2.to_dict(orient='list').items()}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Variant of the same idea `df1.rename(columns=lambda x: dict(zip(df2.stack(), df2.columns))[int(x)])`

Comment: Also a valid solution, however on the given dataset it times at 1.95 ms while using the one-line version of the given solution times in at 383 µs. Likely overhead in doing lambda, stack, zip, and dict, instead of a dict comprehension with to_dict. `%prun` shows roughly 5x as many function calls in the lambda version.

Comment: Haha, yeah,  I've been trying to force myself to time- and memory-profile my code lately and it's been helpful to see how differently similar solutions behave "under the hood"